# MS DynamicsNAV Web service index out of bounds

Tags: c#, navision, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2009

Hi Im having problems with Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2009 R2 Web Service!

There is a webMethod given called **OrderGoodsInsert** which needs parameters **lLanguageId [int], lRec [Text 250] [100]**

lRec should be a string array with values such as these

1. "Document Type"
2. "Document No."
3. "Line No." - (empty at creation)
4. "Insert User"
5. "Modify User"
6. "Type" [0 – „”, 1 – G/L Account, 2 – Item, 3 – Resource, 4 – Fixed Asset, 5 – Charge (Item)]
7. "No." – item code
8. Quantity

Using c# code I try to call the method that is added as a web service reference to my project. The code:

```
string[] arr = new string[8];
arr[0] = "1";
arr[1] = currentDocNo;
arr[3] = "SU04";
arr[5] = "2";
arr[6] = item.Code;
arr[7] = item.Amount;
arr[2] = "";
arr[4] = "";

navWS.OrderGoodsInsert(1062, arr);
```

But when I do I get

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' 
occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException'
occurred in System.Web.Services.dll
```

The error is that `index out of bounds`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How does the SOAP Request for `OrderGoodsInsert` look? Is this a Server-Side Exception or Client-Side? Add the WSDL Part for your Function to the Question, please.

Comment: Also, what value does `item.Code` contains?

Comment: a string for example "0067444"

Comment: https://dpaste.de/PHBd hope I understood wat you wanted

Comment: From NAV side, lRec is a Text250 variable with 100 dimensions, right? Then, I believe, arr variable should be of size 100 and not 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the developer of the WS made changes and did not send out a new documentation.
One more string was needed in the array which represented the shelf the item is on.

Answer (score 0):

Your `OrderGoodsInsert` method looks on the SOAP Definition like this

```
<sequence>
  <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="lLanguageId" type="int"/>
  <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="lRec" type="string"/>
</sequence>
```

So it's expecting an `string` for the variable `lRec` and not a `string[]`.

Try to convert the Array to one single String with a delimiter.

```
navWS.OrderGoodsInsert(1062, string.Join(";", arr));
```

But i am not sure which one is the right delimiter for NAV WebServices.

Comment: Well when i do it like i did with the array i get thrown to `reference.cs` file which contains the function I am trying to call https://dpaste.de/Me2m

it is generated when adding the webReference to the project.

`object[] results = this.Invoke("OrderGoodsInsert", new object[] { lLanguageId, lRec});` is the line that throws the exception.

Comment: @HellOfACode `index out of bounds` normally means your array is bigger than expected. Is this exception already the answer of the Webserver? Could it be, that one of the columns of `IRec` is auto-created and not exposed to the WebService? Maybe `Line No.` ?

Comment: Im trying to contact the developer of the documentation for our company. Will update soon.